# How to deal with overlapping Gmail filters

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I have a Gmail account and a live.unc.edu account. The live.unc.edu account forwards to my Gmail account. I've made a Gmail label called “UNC” and set up a filter to catch all email that is `to: xxx@live.unc.edu` and *Skip the Inbox* and apply the label “UNC”. I now have email that goes to xxx@live.unc.edu with "JIRA" in the subject. I want Gmail to apply the label “JIRA” to that email and NOT UNC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adjust your existing `To` filter to apply to emails that go `to:(xxx@live.unc.edu)` AND `subject:(-JIRA)`.

So for instance, in this screenshot, I have filtered all emails from Facebook that do not contain the word `photos` in the subject:

[image]

Then you can add another filter that applies the JIRA label to the emails of your choice.